# Como armazenar registro em nova coluna dentro da tabela wp_users? (Wordpress)

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress

Depois do usuário preencher um formulário de registro, esse formulário passar por todas as validações, os dados precisam ser inseridos na tabela **wp_users**, a função abaixo está fazendo esse papel no meu THEME:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( apply_filters( 'noo_create_user_data', $new_user ) );
```

Até ai tudo bem, porém foi criada uma nova coluna (user_cnpj) na tabela e é necessário que o CNPJ informado pelo usuário seja registrado nesse campo.

Qual seria a melhor forma para eu armazenar esse dado corretamente?

**Obs.:** Atualmente o campo **user_cnpj** existe na tabela, porém o registro está sendo armazenado como **NULL**, por causa do `wp_insert_user`, os outros campos estão guardando os campos corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não crie novas colunas nas tabelas originais do WordPress, isso nunca é uma boa ideia.**

Se você precisa armazenar o CNPJ use `add_user_meta` ou [`update_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/). Os dados serão salvos na tabela `wp_usermeta`:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
```

Answer (score 2):

[Conforme o Ricardo citou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207883/como-armazenar-registro-em-nova-coluna-dentro-da-tabela-wp-users-wordpress/207949#207949), não altere as tabelas do WP, futuramente isso poderá ser um grande problema.

Utilize a função citada, `update_user_meta`.

Abaixo um exemplo completo de como adicionar o campo na tela de edição do usuário e também como salvar. O código é funcional, caso queira testar, adicione ao seu `functions.php`.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_field_cnpj_custom_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_field_cnpj_custom_profile' );
function add_field_cnpj_custom_profile( $user ) {
?>
    <h3><?php _e("Dados extra", "blank"); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="cnpj">
                    <?php _e("CNPJ"); ?>
                </label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'cnpj', $user->ID ) ); ?>" />
                <br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e("Digite seu CNPJ"); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_field_cnpj_custom_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_field_cnpj_custom_profile' );
function save_field_cnpj_custom_profile( $user_id ) {
    $saved = false;
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'cnpj', $_POST['cnpj'] );
        $saved = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```